# Drawing a star - what is sine and cosine actually in reference to?

Tags: math

I've been given a simple program to write in C#. Some of the mathematics is already provided so you don't have to work it out yourself. However, I don't like to just use things without understanding what it is actually doing. I've got everything working fine. I just want to understand it.

for example:

```
angle = (360.00 / 8) * PI / 180;  
size = 150  
x = 150;  
y = 150;
```

then:

```
x1 = x + size*cos(angle * 1);  
y1 = y + size*sin(angle * 1);
```

I assume that the above formulas are calculating the coordinates using the form y = mx + c with sin/cos equaling the gradient (m). What is the reference point though? Is it calculating a triangle out side of each "wedge"? I don't know a huge amount about radians which is why I am having trouble.

Example of output:
[image: sample star]

Comment: The sine and cosine are making the star a circle. (if the horizontal line is truly horizontal and the vertical line is truly vertical, then you can just use sqrt(2)/2 (with plus/minus signs) as the cos(angle*1)

Comment: The difference between a radian and a degree is as follows: there are 2pi radians to a circle, or 360 degrees. There is pi radians to a semicircle, or 180 degrees. Also, radians are defined to be the angle made when the radius of a circle is measured out along the circumference (the 2 endpoints of the arc, linked to the center of the circle. The angle formed is 1 radian)

Comment: Oh, and the points for the endpoint of each line is computed by adding or subtracting a number from the center of your star. The cos/sin is calculating the fraction of the size to add/subtract from your center. your formula deals with one coordinate at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're just specifying the end points of each segment.

A good way to understand sine and cosine are through the [unit circle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_circle). Here's a picture from Wikipedia:
[image]

To explain this, the point can be at different position on the circle. This can be described in two ways. The first is that *t* is the angle, and you also need to know the radius of the circle which is 1, here, which is what's meant by the *unit* circle. This is the natural way to talk about the position of a point on a circle. Also, though, one can describe the position of the point in terms of *x* and *y*. If you do that, you find *x=cos(t)* and *y=sin(t)*. This is basically the definition of *sin* and *cos*, so there's not a lot to understand, it's just that if the position in terms of *t* is then angle, then the position in terms of *x* and *y* is *cos(t)* and *sin(t)*.

So it looks like you're just specifying the end points of each segment.

As you know, *t* can be expressed in terms of degrees or radians. Radians are the natural values here, so it's better to think in terms of radians, and t, these equations must be in radians for the equations to work out. In talking to people, degrees is useful, but in math, it's always best to think in terms of radians. Radians, btw, are just the circumference of the arc, so all the way around the unit circle is *2pi* radians, half way around is *pi* radians, etc.

If the circle is not of unit radius, then the instead of x=cos(t) and y=sin(t), you have `x=R*cos(t)` and `y=R*sin(t)`. And if the circle isn't centered at the origin, you have `x=x0+R*cos(t)` and `y=y0+R*sin(t)`.

Here's some code in Python:

```
from numpy import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n_segments = 8

angle_step = 2*pi/n_segments

for i in range(n_segments):
    angle = angle_step*i
    xa, ya = cos(angle), sin(angle)  # convert the angles into the x,y representation
    plt.plot(xa, ya, 'ob', markersize=15)
    plt.plot((0, xa), (0, ya), 'g')  # plot the line between the two endpoints

plt.show()
```

[image]

I hope it's clear by now that this isn't `y=mx+b`, which is about lines. Here the lines are done for you by the plotting program, and you just supply the endpoints of the segments.

Comment: Yeah, here size means size of each line. In other words distance of the top point from the origin. Since you have to draw 8 line, the angle represents 2pi/8 radian. As you have to line in diffent angle you have to loop through calculating top point and then it came: `x = x0+sin(angle*i);` here i represents a variable points to which line you are about to draw

Comment: `size` in your equations is the radius of the circle, that is, the distance of every point on the circle to it's center.  For the rest, I've edited my answer to be in the form you suggest (where the segments are from the origin to each point, rather than from opposite points passing through the origin as I originally had).

Comment: Nice explanation but i tried it to explain from the user point of view not how it genarated from the theory of circle. Because you have tell it a far ago. Thanks @tom10

Comment: I guess I don't understand what you mean.  You are basically drawing points on a circle, and you say you want to understand how this works, but you don't want to understand about circles.  I'm very much hoping that someone will post an answer that you like so I can see how to thread this needle.  (My suggestion though is that probably just speaking to someone is your best bet, because then you can help guide the info to exactly what you want.)

Comment: Thanks tom. This helped a heap. Appreciate it.